# Apple Pay card "Not available for Web Payments" and "Not enabled for payments on the web"

Tags: apple-store, apple-pay, wallet, apple-card

I'm trying to check out from the [Apple Store](https://www.apple.com/store) on Safari for macOS using Apple Pay.

In the Apple Pay credit card selector, the card I want to use cannot be selected. It's noted as:

> Not available for Web Payments:
>
> (Not enabled for payments on the web)

[image: Apple Pay Not available for Web Payments: (Not enabled for payments on the web)]

The card I want to use but is "not available" is an American Express. The cards that are available are both VISA, one debit card and one credit card.

Why can I cannot select the AMEX? How can I enable it for payments on the web?

Comment: Doesn’t the issuing bank dictate whether a card can be web pay or needs to be an on the device scan for Apple Pay? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201239

Comment: Does the website accept American Express?

Comment: this is the retail [Apple Store](https://www.apple.com/store) so I'm assuming they accept American Express and that this storefront should give the full Apple Pay experience.

Comment: Not necessarily, you might need to use the Apple Store app on iPad or iPhone to use that card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by removing and re-adding the card on my Mac.

1. Mac > System Preferences > Wallet and Apple Pay
2. `Remove this Card...` for the card that's not working.
3. `Add Card...` and re-add the same card. It remembered my card, number, and expiration date... I just had to provide the security code.

Once the card was removed and re-added on my Mac, the same card worked fine for Apple Pay on the web. It worked fine on the same website where it previously said "Not available for Web Payments" just minutes before.

Answer (score 2):

This is typical for some banks to decline their card for use in the web (macOS) payment method.

My AmEx works with the Apple Store in the US via the web (macOS), so it's not just something American Express dictates across the board.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201239

You will see Verification Needed for any cards that the bank has to confirm and you will see not available if the bank has confirmed your payment method, but declines this type of charge.

- They will have to enable your account for this or explain your options.

Contact the bank support for any card in this case - verification needed or not enabled. I have heard that Apple Watch, iPhone are generally more permissive than web or iPad payments in the past, but at this point, all of my cards work with all of my devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, upon opening wallet I realized this was an old card that went missing and inside the wallet menu it clearly stated removed by issuer. So i just added the new one (which was ready to populate with just the security code, as per prior poster) and it worked.